# Splitting a dataset into training and test set in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a dataset and I want to use postgres sql to split it into 70:30 ratio into training and test set. How can i do that. I used the following code but it doesn't seem to work

```
create table training_test as 
(
WITH TEMP as
(
  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() AS ROW_ID , Random() as RANDOM_VALUE,D.*
        FROM  analytics.model_data_discharge_v1  as D
       ORDER BY RANDOM_VALUE
)

SELECT 'Training',T.* FROM TEMP T
WHERE ROW_ID <= 493896*0.70
UNION
SELECT 'Test',T.* FROM TEMP T
WHERE ROW_ID > 493896*0.70
) distributed by(hospitalaccountrecord);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select t.*,
    case
        when random() < 0.7 then 'training'
        else 'test'
    end as split
from analytics.model_data_discharge_v1 t
```

Comment: Random splitting is not repeatable! **random()** will return different results each time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use random splitting is **NOT repeatable**! `random()` will return different results each time.

Instead, you can, for example, use hashing and modulo to split a dataset as Google Cloud suggests.

- Hash using a [fingerprint function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hash_functions) one the columns/features that is **not correlated** to target (to avoid leaving valuable information out of the training set). Otherwise, concatenate all the fields as JSON string and hash on that
- Take the absolute value of the hash
- Calculate the abs(hash(column)) modulo 10
- If the `result < 8` then it will be part of the 80% training set
- If the `result == 8` then it will be part of the 20% test set

Example using BiQuery (I've taken from a GCP ML course) :

- Training set

  [image: ![Test set]
- Test set

[image]

In that way, you get the exact 80% data each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a stratified split, you can use the following code.

The first bit guarantees that each group has the minimum size to be split.

```
with ssize as (
    select
        group
    from  to_split_table
    group by group
    having count(*) >= {{ MINIMUM GROUP SIZE }}) -- {{ MINIMUM GROUP SIZE }} = 1 / {{ TEST_THRESHOLD }}
select
    id_aux,
    ts.group,
    case
        when
        cast(row_number() over (partition by ts.group order by rand()) as double) / cast(count() over (partition by ts.group) as double)
        < {{ TEST_THRESHOLD }} then 'test'
        else 'train'
    end as splitting
from  to_split_table ts
join ssize
on ts.group = ssize.group
```